# Microsoft Graph Api : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to download files from OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph. I'm currently in the testing phase and have not yet written any code.

Here is what I did so far:

1. Created and registered an app through https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
2. Generated a secret, enabled implicit flow
3. Provided it with the following list of Microsoft Graph Permissions:

   **Delegated**: `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `offline_access`, `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.ReadWriteAll`, `User.ReadWriteAll`

   **Application**: `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`,  `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `User.ReadWrite.All`

   4. Used the `code` flow with a scope of `offline_access` and `Files.ReadWrite.All`, got a code and then a token.
   5. Using this token to download a file via `/me` drive works well (`/v1.0/me/drive/items/itemid/content`), but when I try to download or just query other users I get back the error of insufficient privileges.

Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` gets the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cee06586-12af-4768-9135-b9709d7ecb5d",
      "date": "2018-05-29T14:45:48"
    }
  }
}
```

The same happens when I add a user Id. When I ask to get the user's device I get a "not found" response.

I saw some answers to similar questions saying that I should add permissions to my app to Azure Active Directory via the Azure portal, but my app is listed only in the "Enterprise application" section and I don't see it on the "app registrations" section where I can add permissions, in the Enterprise applications section I'm unable to add any permissions, only search.

Note: my user id is the global admin in the Azure portal. This user also is the user that created and owns the application.

Any idea what I may be missing here?

Thanks

**Edit**:

I was able to make some progress, I tried to create the app via the Azure portal and not the applications portal. Now it shows in the app registration page so I was able to add permissions to it.

So now I'm able to view all the users, but still, when I try to view their drive I get the "not found" response:

Calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid/drive` returns the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ec6ed197-15ea-498a-80d0-e2a9f832a0b9",
      "date": "2018-05-29T15:49:18"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can your user access other people's drives? The token you get via authorization code flow is app+user, meaning the app and user must both have access to a resource to get access.

Comment: You can also double-check that the access token contains the necessary scopes at https://jwt.ms, though the /me/drive call should fail if the scopes were not valid.

Comment: @juunas - My user is the global admin so should be able to access other people's drive, as far as I understand. How can I check?

Comment: Right, that is pretty odd. You can try using the Graph Explorer at https://graph.microsoft.io

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`/users`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list) requires you have at least `User.ReadBasic.All` or `User.Read.All` permissions. Since you've only requested `Files.ReadWrite.All`, you do not have sufficient access to via other user's profiles.

Try against using the scope:

```
User.Read.All+Files.ReadWrite.All+offline_access
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be mentioned e.g. here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children? :)

Comment: The request for a given drive item should work just fine. That the OP was calling, however, was fetching the user's (`/users`) or a user's profile (`/users/{id}`). These require `User.Read.All`. If you knew the `id` for a file, calling `/users/{id}/drive/items/{id}` should work with just `Files.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur please note my edit, I was able to overcome the users issue by creating an app via the azure portal and giving it AD permissions, meaning I do see the users now and also a specific user. However I still don't see the users drive. I tried to add to the scope Directory.Read.All but that didn't help. Documentation wise, I didn't see any place in the Microsoft docs that shows that the scope is allowed to be structured like that "x+y" - can you point me to where you saw this? the documentation made me believe that there are only a very few possible scopes, and users was not one of them

Comment: I'm not sure which docs you're looking at but there are  [a _bunch_ of scopes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) used by Microsoft Graph. The `scope+scope` syntax is simply the URL Encoded version of `scope scope`. URL Encoding converts each `space` to a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to resolve this by asking the token without a user :
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service. 
It how has all the required privileges and I'm able to download any file that I need. Thanks to Marc and Juunas for helping me with this.